# How to generate test data using Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012

How do I generate test data using Visual Studio 2012?

I found these 2 articles on how to do it using VS 2010. But what about VS 2012?

- [SQL Server 2008 R2 Test Data Load Using VS2010](http://www.jnrit.com.au/2011/05/15/SQL-Server-2008-R2-Test-Data-Load-Using-VS2010.aspx)
- [Generating Test Data for Databases by Using Data Generators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193262%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

My database is an SQL-Server 2008-R2 database.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did Microsoft change Visual Studio 2012 so much that the article you linked no longer applies?  Also note that the article refers to Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, so unless you have the Ultimate version of VS2012, you may not have the Data Generator features.

Comment: Yeah I'd check the feature list for your flavour of 2012, MS did a bit of feature rejigging. That said I've never had a lot of tie for random tests, seem to give random results, and QA bods won't even start to entertain them.

Comment: I tried both articles (using the Ultimate edition) but the options mentioned in them are gone in VS 2012 :-(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While this feature was in Visual Studio 2010 (if you added VSTE DBPRO), it [did not make the cut for Visual Studio 2012 / SSDT](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ssdt/thread/5ce89ff5-3ce4-4a88-b43b-7da1794697bf) (yet). This does not mean it will not make it into the product before the next release - it is the sort of thing that could come as a feature pack, [power tool](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/96a2f8cc-0c8b-47dd-93cd-1e8e9f34a917) or even in a service pack. [Same with database unit testing and data compare functionality](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ssdt/thread/158edfb4-3712-4468-b37e-f454ad8a984d/).

As I suggested in a comment, in the meantime you could use a 3rd party tool like [RedGate's SQL Data Generator](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-generator/). Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577063/sql-server-data-generation) for some other options. And hang in there. :-)

Comment: Thanks. I ended up modifying this solution [Create Test Data in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118960/create-test-data-in-sql-server) to fit my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Database unit testing isn't supported in VS 2012 at all.

Comment: You're saying data generation plans are gone forever? :-(

Comment: @Místico no, not gone forever. They're just not in VS 2012 yet.

Comment: Or ever. It may be in a later version of VS, but it won't be in 2012.

Answer (score 0):

We would need to rely on 3rd party tools from now on as this feature will not be supported by Microsoft in the future. 
 http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2013/06/24/announcing-sql-server-data-tools-june-2013.aspx
search for "Data Generation is not included and is not planned to be released in the future"

Not a big deal if we use test driven development. In TDD we would have component test touching database (full scenario coverage). We could use the same modules to create test data.